# Not letting me create user codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Currently I have a issue with my admin create in codeigniter.

Not letting me create a user from my form. I have a sql syntax error. and not sure how to make sure to set user_id to 1 if first install.

**Error**

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `username` = 'admin'' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE `username` = 'admin'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-cms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

**On Model**

```
function adminuser() {
$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
$query = $this->db->get($this->input->post('database'));

if($query->num_rows > 0){

echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
echo "Username already taken";  
echo '</strong></div>';

}else{

$query_user = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password')),
'email' => $this->input->post('email')
);

$insert = $this->db->insert($this->input->post('database'), $query_user);
return $insert;
}
}
```

Comment: `print_r($this->input->post())` and post results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you studying the ActiveRecord documentation page. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

You're missing the `FROM`... it's very clear in your output error message.

Try this instead,

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('username' => $username));
```